# Php function returning pointer to another function

Tags: php, function

I want to make a php function which will return pointer to another function. This is what I want to do

```
<?php

function modeMaker() {

return function myMax() {
 echo "max function";
};
}

$as=modeMaker();

?>
```

Comment: Change `return function myMax(){` to `return function() {` and it will actually work with PHP >= 5.3

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not have "pointers", especially not to functions. You have two options:

1. `return` the *name* of a regular function:

   ```
   function myMax() {
       echo "max function";
   };

   function modeMaker() {
       return 'myMax';
   }

   $as = modeMaker();
   $as();
   ```
2. `return` an anonymous function, if you're running on PHP 5.3+:

   ```
   function modeMaker() {
       return function () {
           echo "max function";
       };
   }

   $as = modeMaker();
   $as();
   ```